# How to force a zero to one relationship?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

My requirement is to have a list of classes and students of each class. Each students must be in zero or at most one class. My code is as following, but in database, each student can be in many classes. How to keep each student in zero to one and only one class?

Student item table is as following

**StudentItem**

```
id student_id code
1    1         233
2    5         453
3    1         567
4    6         565
```

**Entities**

```
@Entity
public class MyClass{

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   private long id;
   @OneToMany( cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
   private List<StudentItem> students;
   private String season;
   ...
}

@Entity
public class StudentItem{
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   private long id;
   @OneToOne
   private Student student;
   private String code;
   ...
}

@Entity
public class Student{
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   private long id;
   private String fname;
   private String lname;
   ....
}
```

Comment: Have a field "classId" in your student class. If the field is null, student is in 0 class. If he's in a class, just put the class id in that field and you're done... The way it is designed is indeed more suited for a `1 to many` relationship (I never talk about `0` in relationships, `0` being no relationship)...

Comment: No, don't store IDs of other entities. Use associations. Your mapping is fine. If you want to make sure a student is in at most one class, you should simply have a unique constraint on `StudentItem.student_id`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that it's a many-to-one relationship between `MyClass` and `StudentItem`, with `MyClass` owning the relationship between them.  Further, it *may* be simpler and more straightforward to use a join table between these two entities; this way, you don't run the risk of creating more than one `MyClass` entry in your database.

Think of it like this:  what is the actual effective relationship between a class and a student?  From your description, one class may hold many students, but any given student may only be in one class.

Here's a rough-hand example from memory on how to create it.  I'll assume that there is a joining table between `StudentItem` and `MyClass` called `classroom_students`, with columns `student_item_id` and `class_id`.

```
@Entity
public class MyClass {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "classroom_students",
               joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "student_item_id"),
               inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "class_id"))
    private List<MyClass> students;

    // getters and setters for entity
}


@Entity
public class StudentItem {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "student_id")
    private Student student;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = MyClass.class,
               mappedBy = "students")
    private MyClass myClass;
}
```